Rust: non-primitive cast: `impl Fn()` as `fn()`
The following function
fn ptr_of(f: impl Fn()) -> fn() {
    f as fn()
}

causes this error:
non-primitive cast: `impl Fn()` as `fn()`

What am I missing?
Context
What I'm trying to do is actually slightly different as seen below, however the above example is the simplest form of the problem.
trait FnExt {
    fn do_smth_with_ptr(&self);
}

impl<T: Fn()> FnExt for T {
    fn do_smth_with_ptr(&self) {
        let ptr: fn() = self as fn(); //error here
        todo!();
    }
}

fn example() {
    example2.do_smth_with_ptr();
}

fn example2() {};

I was expecting this to work, because trying ptr_of with a specific function like the following example works:
fn test() {}

let ptr = test as fn();


Fn() is implemented by all closures that don't accept arguments and return unit, but the cast "Closure as Function pointer" is "only [valid] for closures that do not capture (close over) any local variables" as you can look up in the table of valid casts
See also: Why does passing a closure to function which accepts a function pointer not work?
